# how we can get microphone access programatically in safari browser

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am using `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()` to get microphone access, but it's not working in safari browsers (not also in safari-ios).

Comment: Unfortunately Safari does not support the `audio: true` constraint in the [`MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamConstraints/audio) function. And with *not support* I mean they plain ignore it. Sorry, mate.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier So what's the alternative to get the permission in safari.

Comment: Currently there isn't one. The only thing you can do is ask the user if they're willing to use a browser that does support the audio constraint, like Firefox or Chrome.